# Can I add Microsoft Azure WAF as an standalone resource rather than using Application Gateway or Front Door?

Tags: azure, security, azure-application-gateway, web-application-firewall, azure-front-door

I have an App Service (SSL and Custom domain configured at App Service level) for which I would like to add **Azure WAF** protection as a layer that sits in front of the App Service. I learned that I can do this by using an **Application Gateway** or **Azure Frontdoor**. But as a cost optimization approach, can I use WAF only without integrating with a load balancing resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standalone WAF resource in Azure--just the integrated service in Application Gateway and Frontdoor.